# Error running my flutter project : Scaffold.maybeOf(context)?

Tags: android, flutter, runtime-error

> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/git/getflutter-a714b9b006b2208c983b8ecbeb21302f8ccacc13/lib/components/appbar/gf_appbar.dart:312:45: Error: Method not found: 'Scaffold.maybeOf'.
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> final ScaffoldState scaffold = Scaffold.maybeOf(context);
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                                                                         ^^^^^^^
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
  Running Gradle task > Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Could you add the output from running `flutter doctor --verbose` please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing this answer, the [`maybeOf`](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/maybeOf.html) method is not available in the stable channel of Flutter. If you would like to use the [`maybeOf`](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/maybeOf.html) method then you should adjust your Flutter channel accordingly. Alternatively, you could use the [`of`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/of.html) method with `nullOk: true`.

It looks like you might have a [dependency on an unpublished package](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#dependencies-on-unpublished-packages) (getflutter). This dependency is pulling in a [version](https://github.com/ionicfirebaseapp/getwidget/commit/a714b9b006b2208c983b8ecbeb21302f8ccacc13) of the getflutter package that uses the new `maybeOf` method, however you are on the stable channel of Flutter which does not have this method. You could resolve this issue by replacing the version of the package with a published version:

```yaml
dependencies:
  getwidget: ^1.2.4
```

Comment: But i'm not using maybeof anywhere in the project to be honest its not my project from scratch just fixing it but he didn't run till now

Comment: Have you got a git-based package dependency that might require the beta channel of Flutter?